# Is there any way to rename app name in lauchpad?

Tags: launchpad

I have 3 eclipses installed on my mac eclipse jee, eclipse for android and eclipse for php.
all three eclipses are cooming in launchpad with the name eclipse.
Is there any way i can rename app name like 
eclipse jee, eclipse php, eclipse android in launchapad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can by using an Administrator account and renaming the apps in Finder. LaunchPad will show the changed name accordingly.

There also is [this app](http://chaosspace.de/launchpad-control/), which seems to make renaming items and other operations in LaunchPad possible. Unfortunately, it seems to be discontinued, so try it at your own risk.

Finally, if you are comfortable with SQLite databases and SQL, you could manually make the necessary changes in [the LaunchPad database](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18535/where-is-the-launchpad-database-stored-and-is-there-a-way-to-edit-it-directly). I'd advise you to first back up your database before you start tinkering with it. You can use the built-in `sqlite3` command-line client to manipulate this database. You'll want to find the appropriate records in the `apps` table, and update their `title` field.

Comment: yeah actually that's my next question. I have a doubt if i rename the .app file, i think some features may not work.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, but the easiest way to find out is test it. You can always change the name back.

Comment: hmmmm i have renamed .app files. i will updated when i will get any prob.

Comment: @Vivart, I added some alternative solutions if just renaming the apps does not work for you.

Comment: Hi, I can't rename the application itself. Is there a way to rename the LaunchPad shortcut only? Are there any alternatives to the application you linked? Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Fer's answer works perfectly without the danger of renaming the apps. Perhaps it was misunderstood by some.

The easiest way to do this is to open Terminal, type `ln -s` (included trailing space) and drag the App to be "renamed" into the Terminal window **twice**. You should have the full path to the app in your command twice, modify the second path to rename the app, just keep the path the same.

For example, to rename "Microsoft Remote Desktop" to just "Remote Desktop":

`ln -s /Applications/Microsoft\ Remote\ Desktop.app /Applications/Remote\ Desktop.app`

You don't even need to hide the original icon for the app in LaunchPad, as the new one replaces it.

Comment: important to note that you need to make sure the new symlink has the ".app" extension to it in order for it to show up in launchpad, even though it works fine without that extension when clicked in finder.

Answer (score -3):

Create a symbolic link of your Launchpad app:

```
ln -s Launchpad.app Launchpad_renamed.app
```

Comment: The question is about how to rename apps *on* the Launchpad, not the Launchpad app itself.