# How to hide an app from the Launchpad?

Tags: mac, macos, launchpad

Is there any way to hide an app from the Launchpad in Yosemite?
I don't want to delete it or something like that I just want to hide apps that I don't use frequently, and I have a lot of them, putting them in a folder that I ignore makes the Launchpad slow to process, any solution to get rid of them without deleting them?

Comment: maybe see if http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18535/where-is-the-launchpad-database-stored-and-is-there-a-way-to-edit-it-directly may help.

Comment: You best option is to modify the launchpad database.

Comment: I had problems (with Lion) which kept showing old apps (in other partitions). My solution was to Trash the Launchpad db and restart.
OS X will recreate the database.

Comment: Launchpad only contains apps in `/Applications`. Is moving them to another directory an option for you?

Comment: Does it cause no problems to move Apps from /Applications

Answer (score 2):

If you feel that your Launchpad is filled with apps, you can make folders in Launchpad by moving a app over another app.

[How to do this shown at wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-New-Folders-in-Launchpad-on-Mac-OS-X-Lion), this is done in Mac OS X Lion, but will work in Yosemite.

What the content of link describes is how to make folders in Launchpad, this is easily done by moving an app (inside Launchpad) over another app. This will make a folder with both apps in it.

Comment: Please summarize the relevant content from the link, in case it is removed.

Comment: Quote from the question: "putting them in a folder that I ignore makes the Launchpad slow to process"

Comment: You're right, sorry for not reading that properly.

Answer (score 2):

Prepending a dot (**.**) will make the folder or file became hidden. You can do it using Finder or shell. Just change the app name, prepending a dot. To unhide the app, just remove the dot. Note that Launchpad will take some time to see the changes. If it doesn't work, try to reboot.

Tip: in Finder, you can toggle to see hidden files using keyboard shortcut **CMD + SHIFT + .**

Using shell:

```
cd /Applications
sudo mv YourApp.app .YourApp.app
```

As you may know, **mv** command takes 2 parameters: from and to.

To unhide is similar:

```
cd /Applications
sudo mv .YourApp.app YourApp.app
```

Comment: will the app still run if you put a . in front of its name?  Easy enough to check but I thought I would ask.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I changed an apps name Sparkle.app to .Sparkle.app and the file still showed up in Launchpad with the . (dot) as first character in name.

Comment: I don't know the details, but you need to wait a bit... after changing the name, the app was appearing in LaunchPad for a couple of minutes, even I could execute it. But after some time it disappeared. If I change the name removing dot, it will appear again. I am using macOS High Sierra (10.13.4)

Comment: @jmh if you press **CMD + SHIFT + .** in Finder, you will toggle seeing hidden files. Double click on hidden app will launch it without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just Move them out of the Applications Folder. Copy an app from the Applications folder and paste it in a folder like Downloads or Documents.

Screenshots (in order):

[image]

[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/z05ty4qnj73hjzb/Screenshot%202016-08-21%2010.30.40.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2nel0hfiu9hco2w/Screenshot%202016-08-21%2010.31.10.png?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gxnm2lg4v64x5n6/Screenshot%202016-08-21%2010.31.23.png?dl=0

Comment: Images are best linked directly [SE uses its own sub-domain at imgur for this] rather than from somewhere like dropbox, where they can vanish later. I've inlined the first two for you, using different methods, so you can see how it's possible to either directly inline via drag & drop, or use html to reduce the apparent size without altering the actual image [2nd way requires drag & drop first, then a re-edit to change to html]

Comment: This doesn't work at all for me. Moving, duplicating, Launchpad still keeps the pointer to the file in place. Are you doing some manual clearing of the launch database?

Comment: @bmike did you try to reboot?

Comment: Yes  @RubatharisanThirumathyam - tried it on several machines. 10.11 and 10.12 - launch database finds apps in user home folders as well as desktop and /Applications for me.

Comment: @bmike, I have no idea why it's not working for you - I don't really use the launchpad, spotlight is 100 times faster for me than finding the app in Launchpad :)

Comment: Yea I use Dropzone and PMenu.  Simplifies things greatly!